# MDX Get UserName Where UserID

Tags: mdx

Here is my MDX query below:

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Amt Exrate]
   ,[Measures].[Comm Exrate]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NonEmpty([AccSetting].[User N].[User N] * [Cur Log].[Cur Log ID].Children) ON ROWS
FROM [report]
WHERE 
  [AccSetting].[Ag ID].&[113];
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yDHg.png
`UserID =113` is a hierarchies and a want to get the userN of it
I want to return exactly `UserName` of `UserID =113` on Rows. but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: hello is this not the username ? `[AccSetting].[User N].[User N]`

Comment: are you asking to just show `[AccSetting].[User N].[User N]` and nothing else? i.e. no measures ...just the name?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the name *and nothing else* then this should do it:

```
SELECT 
  {} ON COLUMNS
 ,[AccSetting].[User N].[User N] ON ROWS
FROM [report]
WHERE 
  [AccSetting].[Ag ID].&[113];
```

If you want to turn the name into a measure then something like the following, with a custom measure should help:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[userName] AS 
    [AccSetting].[User N].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,{
    [Measures].[userName]
   ,[Measures].[Amt Exrate]
   ,[Measures].[Comm Exrate]
  } ON 1
FROM [report]
WHERE 
  [AccSetting].[Ag ID].&[113];
```

---

To return the columns you mentioned in comment this should work:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Amt Exrate]
     ,[Measures].[Comm Exrate]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [AccSetting].[User N].[User N].MEMBERS 
  * [Cur Log].[Cur Log ID].MEMBERS 
    ON ROWS
FROM [report]
WHERE 
  [AccSetting].[Ag ID].&[113];
```

---

**EDIT**

Answer in this article:
[Get hierarchies valuesName mdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449363/get-hierarchies-valuesname-mdx/31462624#31462624)

Comment: This return ' ALL' for userName :?

Comment: I want to return a dataset such as:
[UserN] - [Cur Log ID] - [Measures].[Amt Exrate] - [Measures].[Comm Exrate]
Steve - 12 - 3343.3400 - 23.1200

Comment: Because the  [AccSetting].[Ag ID].&[113] is a hierarchies, show when we use AccSetting].[User N].[User N].MEMBERS  this return all of user below but I want to return exactly UserN of ID =113

Answer (score 0):

Try having this way:

```
with dynamic set UserN as
NonEmpty(
            [AccSetting].[User N].[User N].members * [Cur Log].[Cur Log ID].Children
            ,
            [AccSetting].[Ag ID].currentmember
                            *
            {
                [Measures].[Amt Exrate],
                [Measures].[Comm Exrate]
            }
        )

SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Amt Exrate]
   ,[Measures].[Comm Exrate]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,UserN ON ROWS
FROM [report]
WHERE 
  [AccSetting].[Ag ID].&[113];
```

Comment: this return all userN are children of `AgID =113` but I want to return exactly userN of `AgID=113`

Comment: Can you show how the output looks after you tried this?