# Get hierarchies valuesName mdx

Tags: mdx

I created a hierarchies like this photo below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErOXQ.png

On MDX query

```
Select [AccSetting].[UserN].[UserN] ON 1
FROM [Olap_report]
Where [AccSetting].[AgID].[115]
```

This query return all `UserN` are children of `AgID 115`. but I want to return exactly `UserN` of `AgID =115`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425656/mdx-get-username-where-userid/31469678#31469678

Answer (score 0):

Think I understand now - the name is is a property of the member.

Create a custom measure that returns the property.

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[NameColumn] AS
    [AccSetting].[AgID].CURRENTMEMBER.Member_Name
  MEMBER [Measures].[NameColumn2] AS
    [AccSetting].[AgID].CURRENTMEMBER.Name
SELECT
  {
   [Measures].[NameColumn]
  ,[Measures].[NameColumn2]
  } ON 0,
  [AccSetting].[AgID].[115] ON 1
FROM [Olap_report]
```

Reference to `msdn`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145583.aspx

---

**Edit**

First check the member exists:

```
SELECT
  {
    [Measures].[<add measure here>],
    [Measures].[<add measure here>]
  } ON 0,
  {
   [AccSetting].[AgID].[115],
   [AccSetting].[AgID].[113]
  } ON 1
FROM [Olap_report]
```

Comment: I don't know why, maybe my OLAP structure was wrong, this query return the ID such as :`115`!!

Comment: try the `.Name` function - I'll edit the answer. although this is the one I'd expect to return 115 whereas Member_Name to retrun the column name!

Comment: @Steven in the screen shot it says 113 in the question 115 .... do these members really exist in your cube. Try the next script I add to my answer as a test.

Comment: 113 and 115 are the same result